# Built-in network card not working?

Tags: networking

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 9.04(Jaunty). After installation I found that network card is not wokring. And id doest not list in "System > Preferenes > Network Connections" So , i got another card from my friend and try to search on internat about my problem but still cant find solution.

Some commands output is here which may be help to solve problem

```
root@mzeeshan-desktop:/home/mzeeshan# uname -r
2.6.28-11-generic
root@mzeeshan-desktop:/home/mzeeshan# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:02:44:4a:45:12  
          inet addr:192.168.5.37  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::202:44ff:fe4a:4512/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3774 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3611 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4307045 (4.3 MB)  TX bytes:583067 (583.0 KB)
          Interrupt:22 Base address:0x1000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:240 (240.0 B)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 B)

pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5e:25:17:a1:18:ac  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

root@mzeeshan-desktop:/home/mzeeshan# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0069 (rev 12)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Auburndale/Havendale PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 12)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 10f0 (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 05)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 05)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation Ibex Peak 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GeForce 8400 GS (rev a1)
06:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs SB Live! EMU10k1 (rev 07)
06:00.1 Input device controller: Creative Labs SB Live! Game Port (rev 07)
06:01.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
06:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB22/A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link)
root@mzeeshan-desktop:/home/mzeeshan#
```

Motherboard is Intel DP55WG.

I don't know what to do next. Any help will be greatly appreciated..
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider installing a newer version of Ubuntu, such as 10.04 LTS (the *Lucid Lynx*) or 10.10 (the *Maverick Meerkat*), as Ubuntu 9.04 will reach end-of-life in two weeks and will cease to be supported.

In addition, hardware support generally improves with newer versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The nonfunctional network card appears to be "Intel Corporation Device 10f0 (rev 05)".

Checking `/usr/share/misc/pci.ids` in my freshly-upgraded Ubuntu 10.10 I see that it is now recognized as "82578DC Gigabit Network Connection", which means there's a good chance it should just work with a newer Ubuntu version.

Intel's PCI vendor ID is 8086, the device ID is shown here -- 10f0.  Kernel drivers usually have a list of PCI device IDs that they support; checking it with

```
grep v00008086d000010F0 /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/*
```

I see that the e1000e driver in Ubuntu 10.10 claims support for your network card.

In short: [upgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes).